# Change background image on mouse over when class is active and inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the background image of a div element on mouse over and mouse out. Also when the div element is active it should use only one single image. Can this be achieved by Jquery or Javascript?

above is the HTML code which has all the three items with the same class name but I have added a custom image instead of an icon

```js
var div1 = document.getElementById("custom_image");
var div2 = document.getElementById("inner_id");

setInterval(function() {
  if ($('#custom_image').hasClass("active")) {
    div2.onmouseover = function() {
      $(div2).find("[id=no_hover_]").attr("src", "img/no-dollar_white.png");
    };
    div2.onmouseout = function() {
      $(div2).find("[id=no_hover]").attr("src", "img/no-dollar_white.png");
    };
  } else {
    div2.onmouseover = function() {
      $(div2).find("[id=no_hover_]").attr("src", "img/no-dollar_white.png");
    };
    div2.onmouseout = function() {
      $(div2).find("[id=no_hover]").attr("src", "img/no-dollar_blue.png");
    };
  }
}, 1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="how-app-work-content-wrap">
    <div class="title">
      <h3>How are we different?</h3>
    </div>
    <!-- /.title -->
    <div class="how-app-work-content" id="how-app-work-slider-pager">
      <a href="#" class="pager-item active" data-slide-index="0">
        <div class="single-how-app-work ">
          <div class="icon-box">
            <div class="inner">
              <i class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
            </div>
            <!-- /.inner -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.icon-box -->
          <div class="text-box">
            <h4>Be Independent</h4>
            <p>We use a customized application tobe <br /> specifically designed a testing gnose <br /> to keep away for people.</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.text-box -->
        </div>
      </a>
      <!-- /.single-how-app-work -->
      <a href="#" class="pager-item" data-slide-index="1">
        <div class="single-how-app-work">
          <div class="icon-box">
            <div class="inner">
              <i class="far fa-handshake-o"></i>
            </div>
            <!-- /.inner -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.icon-box -->
          <div class="text-box">
            <h4>Own Your Customer</h4>
            <p>We use a customized application tobe <br /> specifically designed a testing gnose <br /> to keep away for people.</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.text-box -->
        </div>
      </a>
      <!-- /.single-how-app-work -->
      <a href="#" class="pager-item" id="custom_image" data-slide-index="2">
        <div class="single-how-app-work ">
          <div class="icon-box">
            <div class="inner" id="inner_id">
              <!-- /.inner <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>-->
              <img src="img/no-dollar_blue.png" id="no_hover" style="width:52px;height:58px; padding-top:12px;"></img>
            </div>
            <!-- /.inner -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.icon-box -->
          <div class="text-box">
            <h4>No Commission</h4>
            <p>We use a customized application tobe <br /> specifically designed a testing gnose <br /> to keep away for people.</p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.text-box -->
        </div>
      </a>
      <!-- /.single-how-app-work -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.how-app-work-content -->
    <a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bizzalley/id1087241798?ls=1&mt=8" class="download-btn active">
      <i class="fab fa-apple"></i>
      <span class="inner"> <span class="avail">Available on</span> <span class="store-name">App Store</span></span>
    </a>
    <a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wildnet.bizzalley" class="download-btn">
      <i class="fab fa-google-play"></i>
      <span class="inner"><span class="avail">Available on</span> <span class="store-name">Google play</span></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.how-app-work-content-wrap -->
</div>
<!-- /.col-md-6 -->
```

Comment: Sound like it would make more sense to just use CSS

Comment: Hi, could you please provide some HTML, too?

Comment: @freefaller I already tried using css but not working ... added css for mouse over and mouse out and for active class as well but still no result

Comment: Maybe off topic, but setting an interval to 1 millisecond always sounds like you are going wrong direction. Browser minimum is 10-15ms nowadays (end of 2019).

Comment: @Mustafa - then you got your CSS wrong. Would have been better to ask why that wasn't working, than go down a completely different (and less acceptable) route

Comment: @freefaller I thought using java script would fetch some result as the active class is added dynamically and the last element when selected would add the class active and the after or before mouse hover the image should be x. and if there is no active class then the image should be x on h over and y on mouse out.

Comment: @MustafaBizzalley please take a look at my answer, it should do exactly what you want to. Feel free to comment my answer if there are any questions.

Answer (score 2):

please use css3 to achieve your desired result, thats simple and efficient way.

```css
.myclass {
  margin-top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

.myclass:hover {
  background: url("https://img.etimg.com/thumb/msid-68333505,width-643,imgsize-204154,resizemode-4/googlechrome.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
  eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat
  non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
  ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit
  anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
  adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit
  esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use jquery or javascript. You should get this done using CSS.

> What you have to do is:
>
> - change your `img` into a `div` with a background-image
> - select your `#custom_image` which is [**not**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)
>     `.active` using `#custom_image:not(.active)`
> - add a [**hover**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) to its child `#no_hover`using `#no_hover:hover`
>
> Which means the following CSS selector: `#custom_image:not(.active) #no_hover:hover`.

---

To change the image if `#custom_image` is `.active`, you have to select the child `#no_hover` of `#custom_image` which is `.active`.

> You will get this done using `#custom_image.active #no_hover`

```js
// for example only:
document.getElementById('toggle-active').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('custom_image').classList.toggle('active');
  document.getElementById('active-info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('custom_image').classList.contains('active') ? 'active' : 'not active';
}
```

```css
#no_hover {
  width: 52px;
  height: 58px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150/EEEEEE/EEEEEE');
  background-size: cover;
}

#custom_image:not(.active) #no_hover:hover {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/0000FF');
}

#custom_image.active #no_hover {
  background-image: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150/0000FF/0000FF');
}
```

```html
<!-- for example only -->
<button id="toggle-active">Toggle Active</button> #custom_image is <span id="active-info" style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">not active</span>

<hr />

<a href="#" class="pager-item" id="custom_image" data-slide-index="2">
  <div class="single-how-app-work ">
    <div class="icon-box">
      <div class="inner" id="inner_id">
        <!-- /.inner <i class="fas fa-dollar-sign"></i>-->
        <!-- img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FFFFFF/000000" id="no_hover" style="width:52px;height:58px; padding-top:12px;" /-->
        <div id="no_hover"></div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.icon-box -->
    <div class="text-box">
      <h4>No Commission</h4>
      <p>We use a customized application tobe <br /> specifically designed a testing gnose <br /> to keep away for people.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.text-box -->
  </div>
</a>
```

---

> The following snippet is an example using font awesome icons and using the class
>   `.pager-item` instead of the id `#custom_image`.

```js
// for example only:
document.getElementById('toggle-active').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('custom_image').classList.toggle('active');
  document.getElementById('active-info').innerHTML = document.getElementById('custom_image').classList.contains('active') ? 'active' : 'not active';
}
```

```css
.pager-item .inner i {
  font-size: 50px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #0000FF;
}

.pager-item:not(.active) .inner i:hover {
  color: #CCCCCC;
}

.pager-item.active .inner i {
  color: #0000FF;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- for example only -->
<button id="toggle-active">Toggle Active</button> .pager-item is <span id="active-info" style="font-weight: bold; color: red;">not active</span>

<hr />

<a href="#" class="pager-item" id="custom_image" data-slide-index="2">
  <div class="single-how-app-work ">
    <div class="icon-box">
      <div class="inner" id="inner_id">
        <i class="fa fa-stack-overflow"></i>
      </div>
      <!-- /.inner -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.icon-box -->
    <div class="text-box">
      <h4>No Commission</h4>
      <p>We use a customized application tobe <br /> specifically designed a testing gnose <br /> to keep away for people.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.text-box -->
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Actually on clicking the element it actually changes an image beside it so would it be a problem if I use another on click function for the same element?

Comment: if i get you right, it should not be a problem, because this here is no `onclick`, its a css hover. You could add an `onclick` to the element without losing this hover. If i get you wrong and its another question or topic you should try it and if you get stuck you could open a new question.

Comment: your solution is working great but there is a small problem that I am facing currently. With the class being inactive if I hover over the element it is changing to "y" image but on mouse out it is still the "y" image where as it should by default remain as x image . But when the class is active then everything is fine

Comment: in your question you told us that you want to hover an image only if the parent is not `.active`. So if the parent is not `.active` theres a hover from X to Y (hover means while the mouse is over it, so it changes back to X if the mouse gets out) and if the parent is `.active` nothing happens, the image still be the same. Or do you want the image to be Y instead of X if the parent is `.active`? (For a better understanding X is grey and Y is blue in my example.)

Comment: Yes exactly. when the parent is not active the default image should be x and then on mouse hover it should be y. if parent is active then the image should change to y, even if there is a mouseover or mouse out the image should be y.

Comment: Edited my answer, its only one more CSS rule. In this case for `#custom_image.active #no_hover`

Comment: Hi @J.Sadi thanks for asking. I have tried it but the default x image when class is inactive isn't showing up inside the div element. So I am thinking to convert the image to fontawesome icon and then apply the css. Will that be a feasible workaround?

Comment: did you run the codesnippet here in stack overflow? for me the default image when class is inactive is showing up... could it be that your problem is, that not each element has the id `#custom_image`? even if you set this id to each element, it would not work becaus an id has to be unique. in this case please replace each `#custom_image` inside my provided CSS with `.pager-item`. This should work.

Comment: ummm yeah I have tried it @J.sadi and your solution is very useful but in my project there is a circular div with white background and inside that I have to put an image with blue color and then on hover it should replace to white image as the circle will be filled with blue color. But your solution solved my 99% of the problem but then again converting the image to icon was the solution that I preferred.

Comment: @MustafaBizzalley for me it was not clear in your question, that you want to change the color of an icon, but converting should not be a problem. I've added an example using font awesome icons below the first snippet. I also changed the css from the ids to the classNames. If you like to learn more about CSS you should give [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/) a try. its for free. :)

Answer (score 0):

**CSS ONLY**

1. Set *background-image* to class
2. Change *background-image* on hover

```css
.main-div:hover {
  background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/tech");
  }
  
.main-div {
            width:200px;
            height:200px;
            background-image: url("https://placeimg.com/640/480/arch");
        }
```

```html
<div class="main-div"></div>
```

Comment: Please consider adding a brief explanation of what you did so that the question author can better understand your solution

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use any jQuery to achieve what you want, it can all be done via CSS using the `:hover` pseudoclass, and the class name.

Here is an example... where as normal it will be pink, with a hover over it's light-blue... then if you click the checkbox it will add the `activeClass` class to the `<div>` so that as normal it will be red, with a hover it's normal blue.

jQuery is used purely to add/remove the class, but everything else is just CSS...

```js
$(function(){
  $("#changeClass").on("click", function() {
    $("#myDiv").toggleClass("activeClass", $(this).is(":checked"));
  });
});
```

```css
#myDiv {
  padding:50px;
  /* Normal, pink */
  background-color:pink;
}
#myDiv:hover {
  /* Hover, lightblue */
  background-color:lightblue;
}
#myDiv.activeClass {
  /* Normal + active, red */
  background-color:red;
}
#myDiv.activeClass:hover {
  /* Hover + active, blue */
  background-color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="changeClass" /><br/>
<div id="myDiv">
  Hello World
</div>
```